# Why is Avengers: Age Of Ultron available later in the USA than in other countries?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers-age-of-ultron

This may be slightly off topic, but I'm sure other North America users will be in the same boat as me. Why did the *Avengers Age of Ultron* get released to the world before it was released in the US?

Comment: This should be asked on Movies SE. And the answer is because Disney sucks.

Comment: It is not off-topic here, and [does not need to be moved or re-asked anywhere](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6594/5184).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about movie marketing strategies, and not any specific scifi or fantasy question.   Movies.SE - http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2172/whats-with-the-trend-of-releasing-movies-outside-the-us-first

Comment: @JackBNimble - I've not seen the film yet. Is there a bit where they inexplicably travel to China?

Comment: I understand them to be traveling to Eastern Europe as well as Wakanda.

Comment: @JackBNimble, I suggest that it falls under the "**Behind-the-scenes and fandom information**" line item of valid site topics and should therefore be retained here.  It's absolutely of interest to those of staring at all the new questions that start with "In Avengers Age of Ultron what does ... mean" and gritting our teeth muttering "_MUST...NOT...CLICK_".

Comment: @phantom42 - I disagree, as every example in the meta question has to do with plot discussion, thematic elements, or "behind-the-scenes" info that is pertinent to the watching experience. This question is flat-out about release dates and nothing more. But that's my 2 cents.

Comment: @gowenfawr Despite my interest in the MCU, I have added [age-of-ultron] to my ignore list for that very reason.

Comment: @KSmarts thankyou thankyou thankyou!  ([Directions here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics) for anyone else who might not have known how to do that.)

Comment: Agree with @Omegacron. Voting to close.

Comment: @JackBNimble The US constitutes about 5% of the world's population: that's a pretty small minority. In fact, it's about the proportion of the Asian population of the USA. So imagine yourself in the alternate universe where you're complaining that movies always used to get released in the Chinatown cinemas first and why are they now releasing them outside Chinatown first?

Comment: @DavidRicherby - the US may only represent 5% of the world's population, but what percentage does it represent of the theatre audiences? Half the world or more doesn't even have access to theatres, so that 5% statistic is useless even if it's accurate.

Comment: @Omegacron i think the US brings in the single most money of anyone one country in ticket sales. i believe i saw the US makes up 20% or more of total world wide sales on these movies. plus the toys, dvds, ect that are going to fly off the selves.

Comment: @DavidRicherby if the movie was made in chinatown i expect it to be released in china town first, the movie was made by a US company, with US actors, with US money, so i expected it to be seen first in the US. but phantoms answers about it building up additional hype in the US makes sense as it gets us jealous and we spend even more money seeing it.

Comment: @Himarm I agree that the analogy isn't perfect. But in what sense "made with US money"? You just said in your previous comment that 80% of the income comes from outside the US.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The money invested to create the movie is not the money it makes in theatres after release

Comment: I agree with @JackBNimble; I'm voting to close this question as off-topic and belongs on movies.stackexchange.com: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2172/whats-with-the-trend-of-releasing-movies-outside-the-us-first

Comment: @N.Soong It's on-topic on both. There is absolutely ZERO reason to migrate it.

Comment: Sorry @phantom42, but I still think that asking why a particular movie was released earlier intentionally in one country (or not in one country), irrespective of its genre, is not suited to this site!  If the OP was asking about whether there was an in-universe reason, that would be different, but as it (and the answer) are based not on this or the production, but more a marketing strategy, I can't see this as being on-topic.  My VTC still stands.

Comment: @N.Soong I suggest you chime in on [the related meta question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6594/5184) and see if you can sway the community consensus.

Comment: @phantom42 funny you should mention that as I just had a look at it.  The only point made in the answer that could save this question is about the 'behind the scenes and fandom information', but I still don't see that as being a valid category to put this question into.  Behind the scenes for work is one thing, but looking at the real-world market strategy?  Just because it's a movie with a genre that falls into our realm doesn't mean we have to work with everything to do with that piece of work!  I don't think it's appropriate for the scope of this site.

Comment: @phantom42; the way I see this question, it would be analogous to asking "Why were Yu-Gi-Oh collectibles put into 'Twisties' packets?"  Know, although this is a far more interesting question and I may be exaggerating a bit, I just think we're drawing a long bow to say that this is in the scope of this site (so call me conservative!)

Comment: @N.Soong As the answer in meta discusses, we're a good target audience for the question which asks about Marvel Studios. The question *could* have been broader, but it was specific to *Age of Ultron* and Marvel. If you don't like the question, feel free to downvote it.

Comment: @phantom42 - as Boris the Animal would say: "Let's agree to disagree" ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because they make more money overseas, and helps drive up the interest in the US - resulting in even more money for the studios.

CBS news wrote up a [nice article about this a while back](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/why-more-and-more-blockbusters-are-premiering-abroad/).

> "We've reached the point now where a blockbuster film can make as much as 80 percent of its overall box office gross outside of the United States," says Dave Karger, chief correspondent for Fandango.com. "So it makes sense that the studios are catering to the overseas markets by releasing many of their biggest tent-pole movies internationally first and even adding special footage in the most important markets."
>
> Paul Dergarbedian, box office analyst for Hollywood.com, says the same thing, releasing movies overseas ahead of the U.S. rakes in more cash worldwide -- and it helps to build hype for the U.S. In other words, don't underestimate the power of cinema jealousy.
>
> "First and most importantly it builds excitement in the countries where the film is not yet playing. In other words, news of blockbuster returns overseas only serve to raise awareness and excitement in North America and as such I believe lead to bigger returns once the film lands stateside," says Dergarbedian. "'The Avengers' last year and 'Iron Man 3' are two great examples of films that opened to bigger-than-expected results in North America due to the fervor and pent up demand for these film by American audiences."

More recently, Kevin Feige addressed this exact question at a special screening of the movie. The answers were [reported back to Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/350fsy/kevin_feige_on_avengers_age_of_ultron_will/)

> Why did it open up overseas early?: [Kevin Feige] says this trend started around Iron Man 2/Thor and they wanted to see how it worked out - he said many countries have holidays [sic] end of April, so it made sense to open it early. They felt no hit in the box office, so it continued. Also allowed distributors to tout foreign numbers going into domestic release

Comment: This isn't even the first MCU film to be released like this.  It's just the highest-profile one.

Comment: Adding as comment because I can't find the article to reference but I read that bootlegs hurt sales more internationally than domestically. Meaning if a cam bootleg comes to the US before the movie is released, it doesn't affect sales as much as if that same bootleg hit before international release. So releasing internationally first makes sense in that aspect as well

Comment: @WizardKnight That was actually addressed in the article I posted.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I read your post but must have missed that

Comment: @WizardKnight No worries. I didn't mention it in the actual posted answer. It's just in the linked source article.

Comment: **TL;DR** - Because: Cash Money!

Comment: @WizardKnight Makes sense really, if 80% of your profit is from overseas, a bootlegged US -> overseas could cost up to that 80%, where as the other way around a bootlegged overseas -> US would at most cost you 20%, assuming absolutely nobody visits the cinema anymore once your bootleg comes out.

Comment: @Theik, still no reason why not releasing the movie at the same time both in the US and elsewhere.

Comment: In the winter soldier movie many countries had a custom scene with cap reading things he missed since he was frozen, each country the list was different. I remember seeing lots of 9gag and reddit posts about that, it is essentially free publicity.

Comment: Well, Cinema Jealously. Were you jealous?

Comment: “"We've reached the point now where a blockbuster film can make as much as 80 percent of its overall box office gross outside of the United States... So it makes sense that the studios are catering to the overseas markets by releasing many of their biggest tent-pole movies internationally first”. That only makes sense if you divide the world into America, and everywhere else. I suspect 95% of Avengers 2’s gross is made outside the UK, but we aren’t made to wait.

Answer (score 0):

This practice started becoming more common perhaps 15 years ago (coinciding roughly with when large swathes of the world, most notably China, started getting sufficiently affluent to consume Hollywood movies). The main reason given then was piracy concerns.

I don't know if today that is still the main motivation. Perhaps since then they've discovered other advantages associated with an earlier international release.